# POST requests get changed to GET requests on ExpressJS app running on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

POST requests get changed to GET requests when sent to my Express (node.js) app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with an EC2 Load Balancer (type: "application)

Checked the express and nginx logs. Both show the request method as GET.

When I send the request to my local dev server, it works fine. Am sending the requests from Postman.

Feels like I'm missing something obvious, any suggestions?

Comment: I do have 2 listeners configured on the load balancer, one to accept HTTPS, and one to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: Could you try forwarding instead of redirecting? 
Also,  please confirm you are following the standard-procedure and not miss any defined configurations: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Was sending http requests via Postman instead of https. Duh